# .NET Core SDK vs Runtime version for Docker

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app. My machine is running what I believe is the latest SDK and runtime: `2.0.0-preview2-006497-preview2`

```
$ dotnet --version
2.0.0-preview2-006497
```

However, when I build and attempt to run a Docker image, I am getting:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview2-25407-01' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0.0-preview2-25407-01'.
```

If I run the base Docker image directly, I discover that it is reporting version `2.0.0` (no preview) as the version:

```
$ sudo docker run -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
root@523a779f7167:/# dotnet --version
2.0.0
```

I don't get it. 2.0.0 hasn't RTMed, has it? I can't find any information about that anywhere online, but I also can't find Docker base images for preview2.

Comment: There is a new [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/) that came out within the last 24 hours. VS 2017 in telling me that my ASP.NET Core libs can be updated to the 2.0 version (non-prerelease). 2.0 may be RTM now. Hard to tell!

Comment: @R.Richards Interesting! Do you know how to force Docker to use the preview2 version of the packages in the meantime? Even if I upgrade the libs, the build will still probably target preview2.

Comment: I have been digging around on Docker Hub to see if I could find one... The best FROM I can see is maybe `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-sdk-stretch`. But I have not tried it; it's like stabbing in the dark a bit. I mean, the tags could be miss leading. Nothing is labelled preview anymore.

Comment: @R.Richards That's unfortunately not it. I tweeted at a few people at MS for help, but given that its a Saturday I'm likely screwed until Monday unless I can magically figure out the actual hash for a preview2 release.

Comment: I also tried upgrading the packages to 2.0 to see what would happen. Most packages upgrade, but: `error: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis with version (>= 2.0.0)`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help! I would love to know what you hear from the MS folks, if anything.

Comment: Silly to ask, but does this work? `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0-preview2`

Comment: @TarunLalwani That isn't a valid tag.

Comment: Ahh, I picked it up from `https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/tags/`. Not sure why its not valid

Comment: In the meantime, you can also install the 2.0.0 SDK from the build pipeline output (the same output has been used for the docker images): https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.0.0/dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core 2.0.0 SDK and tooling have been released by now. Use the latest Visual Studio 2017 Version ([Version 15.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.3.26730.03) or higher) and the .[NET Core 2.0.0 SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md) to get rid of this issue.